# django calculate duration between two timefield

Tags: django

I have two TimeField in a Django model that I want to calculate duration for in another databasefield, or function or class, or whatever best practice.

I later want to use this information to show information sorted on 'prosjekt' and then 'aktivitet'. For example:

> ```
> Prosjekt1
> aktivitet1 = 4 hours
> aktivitet2 = 2,5 hours
> aktivitet3 = 1 hour
> Prosjekt2
> aktivitet1 = 5,5 hours
> aktivitet3 = 0,5 hours
> Prosjekt3
> aktivitet3 = 8,5 hours
> etc.
> ```

This is my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from prosjektregister.models import Prosjekt

class Aktivitet(models.Model):
    aktivitet = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.aktivitet

class Tid(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    prosjekt = models.ForeignKey(Prosjekt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dato = models.DateField()
    tid_fra = models.TimeField()
    tid_til = models.TimeField()
    aktivitet = models.ForeignKey(Aktivitet, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()
```

My view:

```
@login_required
def reg_tid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TidForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tid/tidsregister/')
    else:
        form = TidForm(user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'tid/tid.html', {'form': form})


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TidsRegister(ListView):
    model = Tid
    template_name = 'tid/tidsregister.html'
    context_object_name = 'tidsregister'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tid.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)


@login_required
def tid_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Tid, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TidForm(request.POST, instance=post, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tid/tidsregister/')

    else:
        form = TidForm(instance=post, user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'tid/tid.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Here an `Aktivitet` can have *multiple* related `Tid` objects? Are you sure that is whay you intend?

Comment: I am not sure... When they work with a Project (prosjekt) the choose the acitivity (aktivitet), for example traveltime, or instruction time. Then I want to sum all travel time for one project etc. They first save project information in another model. Maybe I am thinking this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide a full example, I think you can figure out from here:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name="Title",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Period(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Activity,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="periods"
        verbose_name="Activity",
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name="Title",
    )
    start_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Start at",
    )
    end_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="End at",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "Period"

activities = Activity.objects.all()

for activity in Activity.objects.all():
    print(f"Activity: {activity.title}")

    print("Periods:")

    for period in activity.periods.all():
        print(f"{period.title} - {period.end_at - period.start_at}")  # (period.end_at - period.start_at) is a timedelta object, you can get (period.end_at - period.start_at).total_seconds() for example
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and let you know how it goes. Thank you so much for you help :)

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: I didn't find out how to get this to work. Maybe I need to learn more about Django and Python first, as this is my first project… I do not understand output from this, this is all in models?

Comment: You should only define classes in `models.py`. The other parts are for the function in `views.py`, for your case. I'd help more on your own code but I don't understand Norwegian :)

Comment: Ok, I will try to understand how to use it, I think a got some of it by now. In class Period, you have return "Period", is this correct? And I wonder how I can get the project part of this in the result (it is the prosjekt foreign key from another app models). Thank you so mutch much for your help so far.

Comment: I have also added my view for the "tid" app, but I think I need another view to show every project with summed hours for each activity as explained in the first post, and the some code for showing it in the template.